# SSL connection timeout

Tags: git, ssl, github

I am getting the following error when I tried

```
git pull https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git

error: SSL connection timeout while accessing https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

What I am not setting correctly ? How do I print a more verbose error message ?

Comment: Behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: How do I confirm it ?

Comment: If you have telnet, can you connect with `telnet github.com 443`?

Comment: No. I guess not. I was able to run my perl LWP scripts without configuring proxy explicitly though
`telnet github.com 443
Trying 204.232.175.90...
Connected to github.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host`

Comment: Either your proxy proxies telnet too, or there would not seem to be proxy problems. The error message sounds like a network problem though, not an SSL/github one, so you may want to confirm with a friendly neighbourhood sysadmin. Don't have much more to add, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you just use the clone option?

```
git clone https://github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git
```

To debut connection issues, Set the following flag

```
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

Via http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Is-there-a-debug-mode-for-git-clone-https-traffic-td6375651.html

Comment: I was running it on a existing repo.